# error of Jekyll compile the html codes for github page

Tags: html, jekyll, github-pages

```
<pre class="Input" style="white-pace:nowrap; overflow: auto;"><code>Plot[{Sin[1/x]}, {x, -1, 3}, 

 RegionFunction -&gt; Function[{x}, 0 &lt; x &lt; 10], 

 PlotRange -&gt; {{-1, 3}, {-1.2, 1.2}}, 

 PlotLabel -&gt; TraditionalForm[Sin[1/x]], PlotStyle -&gt; Red, 

 AxesLabel -&gt; {"x", "y"}, AxesStyle -&gt; Arrowheads[{-0.03, 0.03}]]</code></pre>
```

The error information is:

```
Error: Variable `{{-1,3}` was not properly terminated with regexp: /\}\}/. Use --trace to view backtrace
```

I use GithShell to use Jekyll(for github page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{` is part of the liquid the templating language. Try encoding the `{` or enclose content in `{% raw %}` `{% endraw %}` block.

Comment: Hi, do you know why my url of this post contains a `%5c` and couldn't be open rightly. [wrong url](http://hypergroups.github.io/mathematica%5Cmath-experiment/2013/09/11/Math_Experiment-Limit) which you can open it from my home page, and the html file is [here](https://github.com/HyperGroups/hypergroups.github.com/blob/master/_posts/Mathematica/Math-Experiment/2013-09-11-Math_Experiment-Limit.html).

Answer (score 1):

because the `'{{'` is thought as part of liquid.

e.g.
`'{{site.title}}'` will be replace to your sitename setted in _config.yml

Comment: Hi, do you know why my url of this post contains a `%5c` and couldn't be open rightly. [wrong url](http://hypergroups.github.io/mathematica%5Cmath-experiment/2013/09/11/Math_Experiment-Limit) which you can open it from my home page, and the html file is [here](https://github.com/HyperGroups/hypergroups.github.com/blob/master/_posts/Mathematica/Math-Experiment/2013-09-11-Math_Experiment-Limit.html).

Comment: `%5c` is in the URL because the category includes a \ which needs to be encoded because it can't be used in a url except as a path separator. It may be best to raise this as a new question.